# check for undefined in hasownproperty in modenizer

Tags: javascript

I was just going through modenizers own version of hasownproperty function and came across the following script:

```
_hasOwnProperty = ({}).hasOwnProperty, hasOwnProp;

if ( !is(_hasOwnProperty, 'undefined') && !is(_hasOwnProperty.call, 'undefined') ) {
  hasOwnProp = function (object, property) {
    return _hasOwnProperty.call(object, property);
  };
}
else {
  hasOwnProp = function (object, property) {
    // DIFF what below  line means I.E. object.constructor.prototype[property] ask J
    return ((property in object) && is(object.constructor.prototype[property], 'undefined'));
  };
}
```

If you look up the secound hasOwnProp function, you will see the following check inside:

```
is(object.constructor.prototype[property], 'undefined')
```

The is condition is defined like so in modernizer:

```
function is( obj, type ) {
        return typeof obj === type;
    }
```

But what i don't understand is this check, look below:

```
is(object.constructor.prototype[property], 'undefined');
```

Why the check for undefined on the constructor of the property ? whats sense does it make ? can anybody explain ?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is "has property" and "the property is not inherited from the prototype". However, I believe the implementation is faulty: `function Foo() {}; Foo.prototype.bar = 1; var foo = new Foo(); foo.bar = 2; console.log(a.hasOwnProperty('bar'), Modernizr.hasOwnProperty('bar'));` prints `true false` (it is not the point that prototype doesn't have it, it's that the current object has one assigned).

Comment: @Amadan ! Thanks btw , do you know the meaning of ur name ... i mean Amadan ?

Comment: Yes :P it is intentional. Reminds me (not often enough) to stay humble. :) But it is very rarely that it gets recognised.

Comment: @Amadan , it means "a fool in a council of wise men" ! ... i think so LOL